# Please modify the code, it gives error that functionRemainCount() does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have taken function "functionRemainCount()" in .js page. I want to call inside the .aspx page . I have used code like this but it gives error that function name does not exit in current context that correct because it is used in .js file. So how to call the function?
Please tell me.

My code is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNote.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", functionRemainCount());
            txtNote.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", functionRemainCount ());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
txtNote.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "functionRemainCount()"); 
txtNote.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "functionRemainCount()");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Attributes.Add()` takes two string parameters.

```
txtNote.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "functionRemainCount()");
```

in this case you need to provide a string of actual javascript code.